# Where is the flaw in my implementing a firstOrDefault function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

I'm trying to practice my Javascript chops and am trying to figure out the flaw in my attempted implementation of a `firstOrDefault` function like exists in C#.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="#resultdiv"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
function firstOrDefault ( arr, f ) 
{
    var result = null;
    for ( var i = 0, n = arr.length; i < n; ++i )
        if (f(i)) return i;         
    return result;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var myArray = [1, 5, 9, 18];
    var myFunction = function ( x ) { return x > 5; };
    $('#resultdiv').text(firstOrDefault(myArray, myFunction)); // should print 9 inside #resultdiv
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/z3h06mwo/

Also, should I instead be extending `Array`? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Have you considered looking into linq.js?

Comment: @TravisJ: He's practicing. If not, presumably he'd use `Array#find` (ES6, already on many modern browsers, easily shimmed).

Comment: Documentation for [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find): *"The find() method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing the *index* (0, 1, 2, ...) into `f`, not the *value*; you're also returning the index, not the value, but you said you wanted it to return 9 so that would be the value.

```
function firstOrDefault ( arr, f ) 
{
    var result = null;
    var value;                                      // <===
    for ( var i = 0, n = arr.length; i < n; ++i ) {
        value = arr[i];                             // <===
        if (f(value)) return value;
        //    ^^^^^          ^^^^^
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Live Example:**

```js
function firstOrDefault(arr, f) {
  var result = null;
  var value;
  for (var i = 0, n = arr.length; i < n; ++i) {
    value = arr[i];
    if (f(value)) return value;
  }
  return result;
}

var myArray = [1, 5, 9, 18];
var myFunction = function(x) {
  return x > 5;
};
$('#resultdiv').text(firstOrDefault(myArray, myFunction)); // should print 9 inside #resultdiv
```

```html
<div id="resultdiv"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: See how I had to add the braces there because I'd added a second statement? FWIW, strongly recommend **always** using the braces. Your IDE can help.

Comment: Is that the only problem?

Comment: @NotDouglasCrockford: Depends on what you want it to return, e.g., do you want it to return the index (above) or the value? If you want it to return the value, you'll want `arr[i]` at the end (or more likely to put it in a variable). There are a couple of *unrelated* problems with your fiddle: You didn't include jQuery and you've given the element the `id` `#resultdiv` (rather than the `id` `resultdiv`, which is what you're trying to look up).